# grunt watch task not targeting correct files - bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, less, watch

I'm a novice with node, npm, and grunt. I only run it to compile my less filses.

I recently moved my git repository from github to a sharedrive. I ran npm install with no errors. All files are in the correct place in the local directory. The 'watch' command starts just fine, but when I make a change to a less file, it doesn't run.

I think this has something to do with the files it's watching but I have no idea what file defines the targets.

I'd love to put some code up here, but I need the file name and I'd imagine you all could shoot me answer faster than a novice could find it.

Thank you

Comment: You have to share your code, because probably you have problems with the watch task related with the directory of your less files.

Comment: > I have no idea what file defines the targets. -> `Gruntfile.js`

Comment: Either way asking this kind of questions at the SO is not a good idea. Finally you should read http://gruntjs.com/getting-started no matter how long it takes if you're going to work with that stuff.